# Translations addon, using JS - derived from ENTITY - *.dtd file

Tags: javascript, firefox, localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

There is something like this:

```
var _ = require("sdk/l10n").get;
console.log(_("hello_id!"));
```

For the new SDK.

How to use this to collect basic translations Firefox `ENTITY` type, eg: `&bookmarkAllTabs.label;`?

How to use translations of the browser, without using xul file?
For example I have such a function, which I used dynamically:

```
var batl = _("&bookmarkAllTabs.label;"); // for example

function addMenuItemBMB(idNadane, window) {
    var item = window.document.createElement("menuitem");
        item.setAttribute("id", idNadane);
        item.setAttribute("label", batl );
        item.setAttribute("accesskey", "&bookmarkAllTabs.accesskey;");
        item.setAttribute("command", "Browser:BookmarkAllTabs");
        item.setAttribute("class", "menuitem-iconic subviewbutton");
    return item;
}
```

I want the `label` to display the localized name of the label.

Comment: Nice post man. Till today I don't know how to localize, it's something I badly need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use SDK l10n to read or work with DTDs (the SDK does not use DTDs). You cannot later use DOM APIs with DTD ENITITY-s. DTDs are only processed by the parser that translates a document source into some other representation, such as a DOM. There also is no scriptable DTD parser...

If the DTD ENTITY in question was applied to some element currently present in the DOM, then you might be able to `.getAttribute()` the text, which would be the easiest thing to do.

```
// bookmarkAllTabs.accesskey happens to be used by context_bookmarkAllTabs.accesskey
var batl = window.document.getElementById("context_bookmarkAllTabs");
batl = (batl && bath.getAttribute("acccesskey")) || null;
```

If that is not possible, the only way I know to get the string would be to create an XML document that uses that uses the DTD and entity, pass that through the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and extract the string like above from the newly created DOM.

Comment: It is a pity that there is no support for dtd. I'll have to use this circular process.
Hopefully, I'll do it here and throw a module that will do everything automatically, so if I wanted to.